# Javascript Setting a variable equal to another variable

Tags: javascript, reverse, naming-conventions

I recently started learning JavaScript, and have had a little issue with my variable naming. For example, this is what I would normally do in Ruby:

```
no_spaces = 'the gray fox'.gsub(/\s/, '')
=> "thegrayfox"
reversed = no_spaces.reverse()
=> "xofyargeht"

no_spaces
=> "thegrayfox"
reversed
=> "xofyargeht"
```

However, the same thing doesn't work in JavaScript. Here's what happens:

```
var noSpaces = 'the gray fox'.replace(/\s/g, '').split('')
noSpaces
=> [ 't', 'h', 'e', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'y', 'f', 'o', 'x' ]
var reversed = noSpaces.reverse().join('')

noSpaces
=> [ 'x', 'o', 'f', 'y', 'a', 'r', 'g', 'e', 'h', 't' ]
reversed
=> 'xofyargeht'
```

Here, it seems that `reverse()` is the culprit, but it could very well happen with other functions.  Is there an issue in my code that I'm not realizing, or is this just an oddity about JS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) is a mutating method, so its ruby equivalent would be `reverse!`, not `reverse`. To keep the original array, you have to clone it first:

```
> noSpaces = 'the gray fox'.replace(/\s/g, '').split('')
["t", "h", "e", "g", "r", "a", "y", "f", "o", "x"]
> reversed = noSpaces.slice(0).reverse()
["x", "o", "f", "y", "a", "r", "g", "e", "h", "t"]
> noSpaces
["t", "h", "e", "g", "r", "a", "y", "f", "o", "x"]
```

Here are all array mutator methods as listed on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods):

```
* pop()
* push()
* reverse()
* shift()
* sort()
* splice()
* unshift()
```

All other array methods are accessors.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot more sense. (: I guess I'm just used to Ruby have seperate bang methods for most normal methods. ^^

Thanks for the heads up and an easy workaround! :D

Comment: Also, thanks for the list of mutator methods! Green check has been given.

Answer (score 2):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) is a really good resource here:

> The reverse method transposes the elements of the calling array object in place, mutating the array, and returning a reference to the array.

You need to read the docs and make make sure you understand how they work.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. c: I guess I'm just used to Ruby where there are functions and bang counterparts (reverse and reverse!). It's nice to know that I have to keep a heads up and pay attention to which are mutable and which are not!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have done differently is what you initialized your first variable to. In Ruby you initialized to a string you removed spaces from. In JavaScript you initialized it to an array of characters from a string you removed spaces from.

The correct JavaScript solution would be:

```
var noSpaces = 'the gray fox'.replace(/\s/g, '')
noSpaces
=> "thegrayfox"
var reversed = noSpaces.split('').reverse().join('')

noSpaces
=> "thegrayfox"
reversed
=> 'xofyargeht'
```

Indeed, as thg435 pointed out, the JavaScript reverse() method changes the array in place, but the array is only temporary anyway, so it doesn't matter that it's altered (in this case).

NOTE: Character is just a fancy word i used here for string with length 1 in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! The only reason I moved it to an array first is because you can't call reverse on a string like in Ruby. ^^ Had I known that it was a mutable function, I might have thought otherwise. :O

What you provided does seem more logical though, even if reverse wasn't a mutable function. ^^

Comment: There are still the same operations performed though. The difference is just in what your first variable points to.

Comment: Yes, I do get what you're saying. It's a subtle difference, but quite the important one in this case!